# nLog Layout: name of .cs file and row number

Tags: layout, nlog

How to configure NLog Layout to get a source file name and row number ?

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `${callsite}` LayoutRenderer should do what you want.

http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Callsite_layout_renderer